# java script: 3 + 0 = 30

Tags: javascript, syntax, decimal, calculation

JavaScript:

```
console.log('adding' + addThis + '+' + p1 +'=' + (addThis + p1));
```

Console in browser returns: `adding3+0=30`

Im debugging a loop that interpolates two numbers. It works fine until `addThis` (the amount that needs to be added to the original number) is exactly 3 and `p1` (the original value) is 0.
Every time the difference(`addThis`) has no decimals a wrong calculation happens.
So same problem at:

```
adding6+0=60 ...or at..
adding9+0=90
```

...all cases in between work fine (e.g. console returns: `adding3.5999999999999996+0=3.59999999999999960`)

Dose it 'forget' the point?
Dose it treat those values as strings?

I can't share the whole code but the problem has to be in this simple calculation right?

Thanks a lot for your thoughts and knowledge! ;)

Comment: Just switched it from (addThis + p1) to (p1 + addThis).
Console now returns: adding3+0=03
...this helps but still isn't pretty and quite functional.
Answers would still help a lot, thanks!

Comment: Post your loop. We need to see where `addThis` and `p1` come from.

Comment: _"I can't share the whole code"_ We don't want you to. We want you to present the [MCVE] with which you've been debugging this problem over the last couple of days.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3+0=30. It seems like it must be the string (at least anyone variable is string). You can re-visit the lines where those variable values are initialized/changed. Else you can use like the below:

```
addThis=Number(addThis); p1=Number(p1);   
console.log('adding' + addThis + '+' + p1 +'=' + (addThis + p1));
```

Comment: Great!  'p1' gets converted from a string...
I didn't know the simple 'Number' declaration as well. So simple – but if you don't know about it you can't search for it haha
Have a great day!

Comment: HaHaHa. You too have a great day! :D

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert the strings to integers you can use the [parseInt function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt):

```js
addThis = '3'
p1 = '0'
console.log('adding' + addThis + '+' + p1 +'=' + (parseInt(addThis) + parseInt(p1)))
```

Comment: Thanks it works. But the decimals get lost. Just looked up how parseInt works – great to know and usefull but I'll need those decimals ;)